# Custom fonts in Twilio Flex Web chat

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I am editing the UI of my Twilio Flex web chat plugin. How do I edit the font, so it's not Open Sans?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS applied to `.Twilio-RootContainer` in order to top-level edit your webchat